# Formant bandwidths

Tags: z-transform, speech-processing, lpc

I have some intuition about bandwidths from these videos ([1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5TP2uG_O2M) and [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mELFJIZ9cEY)) explaining how the frequency response corresponds to the Z-surface.

The only thing I could find on the internet about calculating the bandwidths is [this matlab tutorial](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/formant-estimation-with-lpc-coefficients.html):

> The bandwidths of the formants are represented by the distance of the prediction polynomial zeros from the unit circle.

```matlab
[frqs,indices] = sort(angz.*(Fs/(2*pi)));
bw = -1/2*(Fs/(2*pi))*log(abs(rts(indices)));
```

but `bw` is not the distance to the unit circle but the log of the norm.

This is assuming the roots/poles are inside the unit circle or `bw` will be negative. But I'm unclear why the roots/poles shouldn't be outside the unit circle?

I can see that the relationship of the bandwidth is not linear with the root/pole position (relative to the unit circle), but why is it logarithmic?

Perhaps, if the root/pole is outside of the unit circle we should reflect `log(x)` around `1` i.e. `log(2-x)`:

```matlab
bw = -1/2*(Fs/(2*pi))*log(2-abs(rts(indices)));
```